# JQuery how to check if NONE of the elements in a set have MULTIPLE class names

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-selectors, filter

UPDATE:
Jared's answer was the solution - here is my code, where I just added the else statement to perform the hide/show of the list items if indeed there were a matching set.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form#filterForm").submit(function () {
    var type = $("select#typeList option:selected").val();
    var style = $("select#styleList option:selected").val();
    var items = $(".container .content ul li").filter('.' + type + '.' + style);

    if (!items.length) {
        alert('no items...');
        return false;
    } else {

   $(".container .content ul li").hide();
 $(".container .content ul li"+type+style).show();
 mCustomScrollbars();
 return false;
    }

});
});
```

end update.
I have some code working but I am having trouble taking it to the final step. I have a list of thumbnails in an unordered list.

```
<div class="content">
            <ul>
            <li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-commercial category-traditional"><img src="thumb_test-image1.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images category-residential category-contemporary"><img src="thumb_test-image2.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-commercial category-contemporary"><img src="thumb_test-image3.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-commercial" ><img src="res1-2-THUMB.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-interior-design"><img src="res1-2-THUMB.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-interior-design"><img src="res3-3-THUMB.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-residential category-contemporary" ><img src="thumb_test-image2.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-commercial category-traditional"><img src="thumb_test-image1.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-interior-design" ><img src="res1-2-THUMB.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-commercial category-contemporary"><img src="thumb_test-image3.jpg" /></li><li class="portfolio_images type-portfolio_images category-interior-design"><img src="res1-2-THUMB.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Each list-item will have multiple categories. I have a form with 2 select fields, and I am using jQuery to get the value of the select fields, which correspond to the classNames in the list-items - these are set as variables and used to show and hide the list-items accordingly.

```
 <form id="filterForm" action="">
<select id="typeList" name="typeList">
<option value=".portfolio_images">All</option>
<option value=".category-commercial">category-commercial</option>
<option value=".category-residential">category-residential</option>
</select>

<select id="styleList" name="typeList">
<option value=".type-portfolio_images">All</option>
<option value=".category-traditional">category-traditional</option>
<option value=".category-contemporary">category-contemporary</option>
</select>
<input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="submit" label="submit" />   </form>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form#filterForm").submit(function () {
var $selectTypeClass=$("select#typeList option:selected").val();
var $selectStyleClass=$("select#styleList option:selected").val();
$(".container .content ul li").not($selectTypeClass+$selectStyleClass).hide();
$(".container .content ul li"+$selectTypeClass+$selectStyleClass).show();
mCustomScrollbars();
return false;
});
});
 </script>
```

This works really well. However, I have some cases where an item will have one category, but not the other: for example, it may have 'category-traditional' but NOT 'category-residential'. So what I am looking to do, is test or check to see is there are NO items that match both selected classes, to show an alert message ("none of the items matched both selections, etc"). Otherwise, if there are any that match both, go ahead and perform the function as normal.

I am having a world of trouble because I tried using each() to test, but that didn't work because it would loop through the list and always return the alert - because it basically stops on the first

in the list that doesn't match and then breaks out of the loop.

So how would I go about setting it up to check if NONE of the items match both selected classes? Would I have to index the whole set somehow and check it as a whole, as opposed to the iteration that occurs with each() ? Stumped here - any help, I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple classes in CSS (and Sizzle) selectors like .class1.class2. Just search for elements specifically with both classes and test the length:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form#filterForm").submit(function () {
        var type = $("select#typeList option:selected").val();
        var style = $("select#styleList option:selected").val();
        var items = $(".container .content ul li").filter('.' + type + '.' + style);

        if (!items.length) {
            alert('no items...');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jared! This worked like a charm - I'm thankful that it was a simple solution, I knew it had to be something to do with getting the index.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the hasClass JQUERY function?

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

It sounds like that's what you're looking for...If not let me know and I'll try to help further.

Comment: Thank you - the hasClass function was helpful in getting started, but what I finally needed was based on Jared answer: to basically get an index array of all the items and check, if none of the items matched the combined classes.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help a bit. I appreciate the comment =)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `$.filter(function(index))` function to count elements which have multiple classes and then compare the count to the full list of items.

**Elements with multiple classes**

```
var filtered = $('#foo li').filter(function() {
    return this.className.trim().indexOf(' ') > 0;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t4HfL/

Because this simply checks if there is a space in the className property of each element, note the use of `trim()` to ensure that we don't return elements with extra whitespace, i.e. `class="foo "`.

Comment: Thank Nathan - This wouldn't work in my situation, because I didn't mention it here, but this is going to be part of a WordPress site, and the list items are going to have classes based on WordPRess' post_class template tag - which outputs numerous class names. I used Jared's sugestion, it worked like a charm.